# Lightning: open in sub-tabs when click on list-view records

Tags: lightning, related-list, record

In lightning:

Is that possible for list-view records to open in sub-tabs so that I can easily switch back and forth between the records? I have a custom_object and when the user clicks on the record open in a new tab?

Comment: I don't think that's doable in the standard Lightning apps. You could try to set it up in a Lightning Console app, which handles that automatically

Comment: is that even possible in clicking on records? I think by mistake I have said related-record, what I mean by that is a when you see the records in listview clicking on those records

Comment: It should work on records from list views as well, just that it will create a new primary tab for that record. Clicking on any related records in that primary tab will open a subtab under that tab for the related record. Check this out for an example: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_tabs_primary_subtab.htm&type=5

Comment: thanks but it says `console app` i don't have a console app it's just a regular salesforce app with custom object tabs and also it show the link you provided how to turn on tab/sub-tabs

Comment: Sorry, that's kind of what I was getting at, you can't use the primary/sub tabs out the box in standard Lightning apps, but can consider creating a Console app to get it to work. That link was for Classic Console apps, here's the link to the Lighting Console apps: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console_lex_intro.htm